How to send buffer in Node.js via fetch without get any warning?
I get this warning when seding buffer:
(node:12) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.File is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Here is the code, how can I make it right, not get the warning?
    const blob = new Blob([xml], { type: 'text/plain' })
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('action-xmlagentxmlfile', blob, 'xmlfile.xml')
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.szamlazz.hu/szamla/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })
    const text = await response.text()
    await db.collection('logs').insertOne({
        service: 'prepareAndSendInvoice',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        severity: 'log',
        message: 'Sending invoice response received',
        status: response.status,
        text,
    })
    if (response.status === 200 && !response.headers.has('szlahu_error')) {


Does this answer your question? How to disable warnings when node is launched via a (global) shell script

No, not enough, because I do not want to hide warning, but understand why the latency when sending the data. Why recipient receives it in 1-2 min delay, though it is a short xml only.

buffer.File is an experimental feature is a pretty clear error/warning message. The node version you are using to run your script has this feature flagt as "experimental" and not "stable" That simple. Either upgrade your node version or use functions/methods that are stable. Beside that, where is your code that uses the Buffer file class? I dont see anything in your code related to "buffer.File".

import * as fs from 'node:fs';
import FormData = require('form-data');

const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filename));

